# PrimeNG table saves selected page after value change

Tags: angular, primeng

I have simple PrimeNG table

```
<p-table [value]="users"
          [paginator]="true" 
          [rows]="5">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-user>
    <tr>
      <td>{{user}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

And more then 5 users in table

```
users: string[] = ['Mike', 'David', 'John', 'Ronald', 'Mark', 'Polina', 'Anna', 'Olivia', 'Amelia'];
```

Select second page in table and then assign new value to `this.users`

```
this.users = ['Gregor', 'Ronald'];
```

But second page is still selected in table, so there is no users in table. See live [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-etwkss)

I demo just delect second page and click 'Change names'. New names are not visible.

Is there a way to fix it from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=159028&sid=ae42fc8769470318b8bb7a23cb31d9c0#p159028), you are out of luck. Limitations are unfortunately part of life when it comes to these frameworks.

However, you can always hack it using the hammer and dynamite approach.

[See the updated plunk.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-7auabe)

Comment: Have to use this fix, Thank you